# Vue 3.0 How to assign a prop to a ref without changing the prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm sending from the parent component a prop: `user`. Now in the child component I want to make a copy of it without it changing the prop's value.

I tried doing it like this:

```
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    apiUser: {
      required: true,
      type: Object
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const user = ref(props.apiUser);

    return { user };
  }
});
```

But then if I change a value of the user object it also changes the apiUser prop. I thought maybe using `Object.assign` would work but then the ref isn't reactive anymore.

In Vue 2.0 I would do it like this:

```js
export default {
  props: {
     apiUser: {
       required: true,
       type: Object
     }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.user = this.apiUser;
    // Now I can use this.user without changing this.apiUser's value.
  }
};
```

Credits to @butttons for the comment that lead to the answer.

`const user = reactive({ ...props.apiUser });`

Comment: Well no it wouldn't be reactive, but couldn't you Object.assign() / JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) / lodash cloneDeep() the user, add a data reference, do the changes to this, and then $emit back the changes to the parent, where you would merge the changes reactively with either a merge or a $set, and then push it back down as a prop?

I realize you're using the new composition api, and I'm no Vue 3 expert by any means, but this is at least the way I've always done it, with Vue 2 for large applications.

Comment: @Abarth, Really? This seems like an inefficient way of doing it. I'm hoping someone knows a more efficient way of doing it. Thanks anyways!

Comment: If you want to make a copy of the prop you have to use Object.assign or something similar. The real question is, what exactly is it you want to do? Why do you need a copy of the prop?

Comment: In your first code snippet, the `return user` should be inside the `setup()` function. And you can destructure the incoming `apiUser` prop when you assign it to `user`, like this: `const user = ref(...props.apiUser);` Now `apiUser` and `user` are two different copies.

Comment: I'll gladly hear of better ways of course. I'll add my method below as an answer, obviously ignore it, if it turns out to not be the answer, but then at least I feel like I've explained myself.

Comment: @butttons I guess you meant `ref([...props.apiUser]);`? Otherwise typescript gives an error that it expected 1 or more arguments but received none. When I use it like I wrote it, it generates this error: `Type '{ [key: string]: any; }' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

Comment: Ah, my bad. For object values, it's recommended to use `reactive`. Pretty sure that won't throw a type error. Try using `const user = reactive(...props.apiUser);`. Here's when to use [ref vs reactive](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/#ref-vs-reactive).

Comment: @butttons almost got it right! It worked by doing it like this: `const user = reactive({ ...props.apiUser });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
props: {
 apiUser: {
   required: true,
   type: Object
 }
},
setup(props) {
   const userCopy = toRef(props, 'apiUser')
}
```

With the composition API we have the [toRef](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#toref) API that allows you to create a copy from any `source reactive object`. Since the `props` object is a `reactive`, you use `toRef()` and it won't mutate your prop.

Comment: I tried `const userCopy = ref(props.apiUser);`. Do you know the difference in this case? Both showed values but only `toRef` made it reactive.

Comment: `const fooRef = ref(props.foo)`

The above ref is not synced with props.foo, because the ref() receives a plain string value.
This is from the [doc](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#toref). 
I don't know if it answers your question

Comment: This answer is wrong.
const userCopy = toRef(props, 'apiUser')
will mutate the prop.

Comment: @PetrPánek it's not wrong, it depends on what you want to do. If you just want to be able to track changes to the prop, for example because you want to pass it to a composable, `toRef` is the better solution. Think of something like `useLoader(toRef(props, 'url'))`

Comment: Saying the using `toRef()` won't mutate your prop is wrong since it's exactly what `toRef()` is made for. `ref()` won't sync with your props if you reassign in, but `toRef()` will.

Answer (score 6):

This is what you looking for: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow

Create data where you add the prop to

```
export default {
  props: ['apiUser'],
  data() {
    return {
      // user only uses this.apiUser as the initial value;
      // it is disconnected from future prop updates.
      user: this.apiUser
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you use api composition:

```
import {ref} from "vue";
const props = defineProps(['apiUser']);
const user = ref(props.apiUser);
```

You also may want to consider using computed methods (see also linked doc section from above) or [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model).

Please note that the marked solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67820271/2311074 is not working. If you try to update `user` you will see a readonly error on the console. If you don't need to modify user, you may just use the prop in the first place.

Comment: I think that If api user is an object in the parent component, and you will update the local data user, this may change the prop, since it's passed by reference, no?

Answer (score 2):

With this approach

`const userCopy = toRef(props, 'apiUser')`

the created ref will try to mutate the prop on change and produce warning.

The correct way to map ref to prop and not cause props mutations is the following

```
const userCopy = ref();

watchEffect(() => (userCopy.value = props.apiUser));
```

Answer (score 2):

#### I think the best way is to clone the prop when initializing the local variable.

This is how I would do it:

**Parent component:**

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Child from './Child.vue';

const user = ref({
  age: 20,
});
</script>

<template>
  Parent: {{ user.age }}
  <br />
  <child :user="user" />
</template>
```

**Child component:**

```
<script setup>
import { ref, toRaw } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps({
  user: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});

const localUser = ref(structuredClone(toRaw(props.user)));
localUser.value.age = 40;
</script>

<template>Child: {{ localUser.age }}</template>
```

**NOTE:** if you just do the reference like this:

`const localUser = ref(props.user);`

It won't work and the parent will still be changed when the age of local reference is changed.

Regarding the method of cloning I prefer to use the native one `structuredClone` which is performing a deep clone, but it does not support some types of objects, one of them is `Proxy`, that's why I had to use `toRaw` a method from vue and now the prop will be a plain Object, acceptable by `structuredClone`.

Feel free to use any deepClone method available on the internet.

For what I saw `structuredClone` is much faster than lodash for example, it's also native, so no extra required code needed to increase the bundle size, and it works for most of the things. 
Benchmark [[here](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/16221/0/lodash-clonedeep-vs-structuredclone)] 
Article about supported things for native clone [[here](https://www.builder.io/blog/structured-clone)] or [[official doc]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)

Don't use spreed operator (`...`) or `Object.assign`, because they are shallow copying, not deep copy, which means that if you have nested objects, it wont work as you would think.

**Stack Blitz working example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-wycfiv?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FChild.vue

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comment section, a Vue 2 method that I'm personally fond of in these cases is the following, it will basically make a roundtrip when updating a model.

Parent (apiUser) ->
Child (clone apiUser to user, make changes, emit) ->
Parent (Set changes reactively) ->
Child (Automatically receives changes, and creates new clone)

**Parent**

```
<template>
   <div class="parent-root"
      <child :apiUser="apiUser" @setUserData="setUserData" />
   </div>
</template>

// ----------------------------------------------------
// (Obviously imports of child component etc.)
export default {
   data() {
      apiUser: {
         id: 'e134',
         age: 27
      }
   },

   methods: {
      setUserData(payload) {
         this.$set(this.apiUser, 'age', payload);
      }
   }
}
```

**Child**

```
<template>
   <div class="child-root"
      {{ apiUser }}
   </div>
</template>

// ----------------------------------------------------
// (Obviously imports of components etc.)
export default {
   props: {
      apiUser: {
         required: true,
         type: Object
      }
   },

   data() {
      user: null
   },

   watch: {
      apiUser: {
         deep: true,
         handler() {
            // Whatever clone method you want to use
            this.user = cloneDeep(this.apiUser);
         }
      }
   },

   mounted() {
      // Whatever clone method you want to use
      this.user = cloneDeep(this.apiUser);
   },

   methods: {
      // Whatever function catching the changes you want to do
      setUserData(payload) {
         this.$emit('setUserData', this.user);
      }
   }
}
```

**Apologies for any miss types**